# Understanding PowerPC Assembler Function with bit rotate

Tags: assembly, powerpc

Im trying to port a legacy app which has some basic bit shifting to decrypt a buffer, but im lost with this powerpc code - i tried my best to understand it and added comments and created a pseudo c function however something is obviously not right.

This is the PPC function, it has one argument i think the buffer (params are: void *,int) http://pastebin.com/RNRAWCpi

this is as far as my pseudo c has advanced:

```
unsigned long long* data=(unsigned long long*)pBuffer; // file data
unsigned long long crypt = 0x0000;
unsigned long long next_crypt;
unsigned int len = size >> 3;

for(unsigned int i=0; i<len;i++) {
    next_crypt = crypt+data[i]-0x9A6C9A19;      
    data[i] = ((data[i]<<0x18)|(data[i]>>0x14))+0x9A6C9A19;
    data[i] =  (data[i]<<0x3)|(data[i]>>0x29);
    data[i] = data[i] - crypt;
    crypt = next_crypt;     
}
```

For example, why is crypt split into two registers r29 & r30

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the PowerPC is 32bit then a "long long" (64bits) would need to be split into 2 32bit registers. Do you have any other specific questions?

Comment: thank you - do you happen to know what my error is with the translation to the pseudo c function? can you see an obvious error?

Comment: It appears your rotates are using decimal format while your C code is hex format "rotrwi    r11, r10, 14" (0x0E) 14 != 0x14 (20)

Comment: ah thank you i didnt see that - do you happen to know a powerpc asm community were these kind of questions are better placed?